# IEquatable documentation?

Tags: c#, iequatable

I have looked through IEquatables documentation from microsoft and have some stuff i do not understand with the implementation of it? well not something what i do not understand is this part

```
   public Person(string lastName, string ssn)
   {
      if (Regex.IsMatch(ssn, @"\d{9}"))
        uniqueSsn = $"{ssn.Substring(0, 3)}-{ssn.Substring(3, 2)}-{ssn.Substring(5, 4)}";
      else if (Regex.IsMatch(ssn, @"\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}"))
         uniqueSsn = ssn;
      else
         throw new FormatException("The social security number has an invalid format.");

      this.LastName = lastName;
   }
```

someone that can tell me why the constructor needs to look like this?

Comment: It's just checking that a valid social security number has been passed to it. (Although it seems a bit odd that they'd do that and then completely ignore the fact that `lastName` could be null...)

Comment: There is nothing related to `IEquatable` in your code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It's from [the sample code from the IEquatable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Whilst this is directly from the sample code in the IEquatable docs, this has nothing to do with IEquatable in its current context. Looking at the docs, this is a snippet of code from their `Person` sample class, of which in the docs the class has more code that implements `IEquatable` and explains how/why. Your question is to do with a constructor that is otherwise unrelated. Is your question instead to do with how constructors work and what they're used for?

Comment: Ah okey it seems alittle bad to include this code though if your trying to explain IEquatable quz people will get stuck on it i think but thankyou for the help